# Spring boot Oauth2 JWT insufficient scope error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to create an authorization and resource server using oauth in a spring boot application and I can't seem to get the authorization working for it.

**`Spring boot : 1.5.10.RELEASE, Java 8, spring-security-oauth2 : 2.3.4.RELEASE and spring-security-jwt:1.1.0.RELEASE`**

---

I have setup the authorization and resource server within the same application and the configuration for the same is as follows.

**Authorization Server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    private CustomTokenEnhancer customTokenEnhancer;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .clients(clientDetailsService());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
        super.configure(security);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(customTokenEnhancer, jwtAccessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }
}
```

**Resource Server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuthResourceConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize**", "/oauth/check_token")
                .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable().requestMatchers().antMatchers("/test**")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/test**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/test**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }
}
```

---

I am using `client_credentials` grant type to issue a new token from the `/oauth/token` endpoint and a new token is generated successfully.

The following is the JWT generated

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsiKiJdLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIiwid3JpdGUiXSwiZXhwIjoxNTc4ODE5MDM3LCJqdGkiOiIzNWViZDNiMi04ZTM4LTRkMDEtYTUzYi01NDU0NzI2NjE1ZDIiLCJ0ZW5hbnQiOiJjOSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImM5In0.G4BFfefKQEWSbvJFUwQ_tPDiHOSNMP9205iJPOv6-w4
```

If I parse this, I can see that it has read and write scopes.

I have the following controller defined in my application

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String token) {}
```

Now when I try to call this API using the given token, I get the following error

**`error="insufficient_scope", error_description="Insufficient scope for this resource", scope="write"`**

I don't understand what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Any reason for the obsolete and unsupported Spring versions? Especially Spring Security modules - not only does it mean that you're unlikely to get the help you need but it also poses a rather large security risk...

Comment: Its an old project. Could that be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Something being old is no excuse for a lack of patching strategy and even less of an excuse for using EOL libraries with no security patching support in production!

Comment: @BoristheSpider that is no the issue here though. Scope checking works just fine even in this older version of Spring Boot. Security risks are not the topic of this question.

Comment: @Gimby that's why it's a comment and not an answer. I see it as important to point out security issues such as these to make the OP aware where perhaps they were not. Just like a question about SQL syntax that doesn't use a prepared statement - for example.

Comment: As to the matter at hand, I am not entirely familiar with this but reading around about it seems to suggest you need to configure the desired scopes in the resource server too, like demonstrated in this [blog post](http://www.zakariaamine.com/2018-03-01/using-oauth2-in-spring-scopes). Worth a try.

Comment: @Gimby: I have already added the configuration suggested in that blog.

Comment: is there any reason why you are using both method security and web security?